# Detect if space is pressed 3 times?

Tags: c, whitespace, detection, getchar

In my program I need to detect if the spacebar is pressed 3 times and then replace it whit a \n.

I am using getchar for getting my input and detecting one space is no problem but if I enter 3 spaces to check it does not work.
Any help is very appreciated

This is my code so far witch works perfectly fine if I only check one spacebar but if I enter 3 of the it will not detect it

```
if (c == ' ')
{
putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: You need to keep track of the last two characters input, not only the current one. A short two-element queue or something like that perhaps? Or just two variables?

Comment: Also note that you don't really detect if the spacebar have beeen pressed three times, all you will detect is three spaces in the input. The spaces can have been copy-pasted into the input, you don't know if there's an actual spacebar press for the space. At least it's not possible with standard C++ to detect any key-presses, it can just see what's coming as input.

Comment: Mark, please add more of your code, showing your reading of the input etc. This will help us help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count the number of consecutive spaces. Something like:

```
int c;
int spaces = 0;
while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    if (c == ' ')
    {
        ++spaces;
        if (spaces == 3)
        {
            putchar('\n');
            spaces = 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        spaces = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much that was helpful

Comment: @Mark, please mark this question as answered. Thanks